# File Attachment from PHP Form Using phpMailer is not sent

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

I try to make my contact form. Till now I have this form:

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">
Name: <input name="name" id="name" type="text" /><br />
Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />
Subject: <input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" /><br />
Message:<br />
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
Βιογραφικό: <input type ="file" name='attachment' id='uploaded_file'>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and this is the email.php

```
<?php
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
require("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->Host = "localhost"; // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port     = 587;  
$mail->Username = "xxx@xxx.xx"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxx"; // SMTP password
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->SetFrom("xxx@xxx.xx","xxx.xx");
$mail->AddAddress("xxx@xxx.xx", "mikroviologos.gr");
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "You have received feedback from your website!";
$mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;
$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachment']['name']);
?>
```

Subject and message is sent normally, but whatever I try, the attachment is not sent. I don't need to save the file somewhere, just to attach it to the mail.

Thank you!

Comment: what does your error output say? I would suspect that as a security precaution that your server environment would prevent attachment of temporary upload files, you should move the file and store it properly before referencing to attach it.

Comment: I put enctype="multipart/form-data"  in <form> and it works perfectly!

Comment: ahhh that old chestnut. Good that you found it Perhaps add this info as an answer to your own question so others can learn from it :)

Comment: You should still do what both the PHP and PHPMailer docs say and handle your uploads safely. Your code is currently unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

I put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `<form>` and it works perfectly!